# DataGridView from database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem when i try to fill a second dataGridview from my database,
the first dataGridView contain the value of the second dataGridView, if i fill the second dataGridView.

Where is my error?

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter;
OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter2;

//Connection
try
{
    connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Errore " + er);
}

//First DataGridView

try
{

    string query2 = "select * from MyTable";
    connection.Open();
    oledbAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query2, connection);
    oledbAdapter2.Fill(ds2);
    DGV1.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0]


}
catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Errore " + er);
}
connection.Close(); 


    //correct assign of value
   string F = DGV1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();


//Second DataGridView

{

    string query = "select * from MyTable2";
    connection.Open();
    oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
    oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
    DGV2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    //correct assign of value
   string B = DGV2.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();

}
catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Errore " + er);
}
connection.Close();



MyVar = DGV2.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();


//Incorrect assign of value for DGV1, inside there are the value of DGV2 the last DataGridView Popolate  WHY??????
MyVar2 = DGV1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, the problem is that inside de dataGridView "DGV1" there are the data of "DGV2", and the variable MyVar2 keep the value of "DGV2".

Comment: _DGV2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];_ ?? _DGV2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];_ ?!

Comment: Tables[1] does not exist.....

Comment: ds, ds2, DGV1, DGV2, Adapter1, Adapter2 ... give your objects meaningful names and you'll avoid lots of issues.

Comment: Ok for the name, i'm agree with you... but why the code does not work??? In this case i don't think that the problem is the name of object....

Answer (score -1):

Try adding DGV.DataBind() like this:

```
DGV2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DGV2.DataBind();
```

and

```
DGV1.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0]
DGV1.DataBind();
```

Comment: There is no DataBind() for a Winforms DataGridView, only for the ASP.NET GridView.

Comment: dataGridView does not contain a definition of 'DataBind'.... if i use DataBind();